# ¿Cómo uso en un método una variable de clase que vale diferente en la clase y su subclase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Supongamos que tengo una clase así:

```
class Hola(object):
    NOMBRE = 'hola'

    def muestro_cosas(self):
        print('Mi nombre es {}'.format(Hola.NOMBRE))


class HolaPequenito(Hola):
    NOMBRE = 'hola_pequenito'

    ...
```

Como se ve, `HolaPequenito` es subclase de `Hola`.

Ahora, realizo una implementación de cosas en las que necesito utilizar la variable de clase `NOMBRE`.

- Si tengo una instancia de `Hola`, haré `print (Hola.NOMBRE)`.
- Si tengo una instancia de `HolaPequenito`, haré `print (HolaPequenito.NOMBRE)`.

Sin embargo, hay veces en las que no sé si estaré instanciando `Hola` o `HolaPequenito`, pues las instancío dinámicamente dentro de un proceso grande, en el cual necesito conocer el valor de `NOMBRE` de la clase que se ha instanciado y hacer algo así como:

```
class Hola(object):
    NOMBRE = 'hola'

    def comprueba_cosas(self):
        if NOMBRE == 'hola':  # aquí debo usar la variable de clase
           ...
        elif NOMBRE == 'hola_pequenito':
           ...
```

Es decir: si instancío `Hola` o `HolaPequenito` sin saber cuál de las dos estoy instanciando, ¿cómo puedo acceder a la variable de clase `NOMBRE` respectiva para hacer alguna heurística?

Lo más conseguí fue [definir un método de clase que me lo devuelva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709024/1983854):

```
class Hola(object):
    NOMBRE = 'hola'

    @classmethod 
    def bah(cls):     
        return cls.NOMBRE
```

Pero no sé cómo combinarlo para interactuar con la variable de clase `NOMBRE` dentro de un método.

Comment: Si solo es acceder a su valor (no reasignar) puedes usar la referencia a la instancia para acceder al atributo de clase siempre que no crees un atributo de instancia con el mismo nombre (`self.NOMBRE`).  O bien mediante `self.__class__.NOMBRE`

Comment: @FJSevilla sí, ¡gracias por la opción! Lo que pretendo (no me expliqué bien, creo) es acceder a ese valor dentro de de un método. Por ejemplo, en `comprueba_cosas` que haga una cosa u otra dependiendo del valor de la variable de clase. Veo que con `self.__class__.NOMBRE`, ¿sería la única opción? Tenía la percepción de que acceder a estas variables de esta manera era un poco "feo".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se puede acceder al atributo de clase desde la referencia a una instancia (`self`en este caso) de varias formas:

- Usando [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

  ```
  if type(self).NOMBRE == 'hola':
  ```

  lo que nos permite obtener la referencia a la clase (`type object`) usando la referencia de una instancia (`self`).
- Usando el descriptor [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) directamente:

  ```
  if self.__dict__.NOMBRE == 'hola':
  ```

  **Acceder usando `__dict__` es considerado generalmente "no pitónico"**, por lo que usar `type` se considera el método apropiado. Esto es común a otros atributos "magicos" como `__len__`, que son semánticamente considerados privados y deberían accederse mediante los medios que proporciona la API, como los buil-tin en estos dos casos.

  Una **excepción** es el hipotético caso de usar **Python 2 con las clases del viejo-estilo** (no deriven de `object`), en tal caso `type(self)` no funciona ya que retorna `instance` como tipo, pero si `self.__dict_`. En Python 3 toda clase deriva por defecto de `Object`, por lo que esto no ocurre.

  Observase que `type` no retorna siempre lo mismo que `__class__`, la propia documentación de la función lo deja entrever:

  > El valor de retorno es un objeto `type` **generalmente** el mismo objeto retornado por `object.__class__`.

  Ésto se debe a que es perfectamente posible sobrescribir el atributo `__class_`_ en una clase derivada. Esto ocurre típicamente, por su propia naturaleza, con los objetos proxy, sin ir más lejos `weakref.proxy` de la stdlib:

  ```
  import weakref


  class Foo: 
      pass

  obj = Foo()
  p = weakref.proxy(obj)

  print(type(p))      # <class 'weakproxy'>
  print(p.__class__)  # <class '__main__.Foo'>
  ```

  Por lo que hay determinados casos (además de las clases de viejo estilo) en los que usar `__class__` directamente en vez de `type` sea la solución o una muy mala idea dependiendo del caso.
- Usar un método de clase a modo de "getter" o "setter" como expones es también una posibilidad.

  ```
  @classmethod 
  def get_nombre(cls):     
      return cls.NOMBRE


  if self.get_nombre() == 'hola':
  ```

  Obviamente es sensible a posibles sobreescrituras o solapamiento con un método de de instancia con el mismo nombre en futuras subclases.
- Se puede acceder al atributo de clase usando simplemente `self.attr`. Esto es así, porque Python primero busca dentro de los atributos de instancia y, en caso de no encontrar nada, busca en los atributos de clase.

  El riesgo es que si en algún momento se define un nuevo atributo de instancia con el mismo nombre (`self.attr = algo`) `self.attr` nunca más hará referencia al atributo de clase, sino al atributo de instancia. Hay veces que este comportamiento puede interesar, pero si no lo queremos, creo que es mejor ser explícito, como el zen de Python sugiere :), y acceder al atributo de clase mediante una referencia a la clase y no mediante la instancia.

Comment: Fantástico, mil gracias. De entre todas las opciones, ¿hay alguna que sea más indicada? La más _limpia_ parece `self.attr`, aunque puede ser peligrosa.

Comment: Por cierto la parte de _Acceder usando..._ está como bloque de cita. Pero es texto tuyo, ¿no?

Comment: Limitándonos a clases de "nuevo estilo" `type(self)` debería ser la opción preferida en general. Usar un método de clase es bastante explícito y también seguro, aunque creo que solo para leer el atributo es complicar la cosa (aunque esto es subjetivo sin duda) pero puede ser la mejor opción para otros casos, como asignar nuevos valores desde la instancia con cierto saneamiento previo. Usar `self.attr` es sin duda la más limpia  como dices y no tiene nada malo en si misma, pero a no ser que no nos preocupe la posibilidad del solapamiento, yo prefiero ser explícito (y no sirve para reasignar).

Comment: En cuanto a la cita... el texto es mio (aunque la idea que expone "hacer `("foo".__add__("bar")` aunque sea posible, en vez de `"foo" + "bar"`, es un crimen que merece  la suerte de Ned Stark" no es mía... XD). No es raro en mi que use los bloques de cita inapropiadamente para resaltar algo :(

Comment: No no, cada uno edita como quiere, es solamente que leo con tanto detenimiento tus respuestas que si hay una cita estoy pensando "¿de dónde viene esto? porque también quiero leerlo" : )